# Использование дебагера с веб-сервером

Tags: perl, отладка

Есть сайт, написанный на Perl и его необходимо отладить. Но при этом используется веб-сервер вроде Apache или Nginx.
Вопрос: как вклиниться в запрос, чтобы запустить отладку скрипта со всеми переданными заголовками и параметрами запроса?

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я знаю, Comodo (http://komodoide.com/perl/) имеет возможности отладки скриптов. Сам не углублялся в него, ибо работаю в другом редакторе. Почитайте, попробуйте.

Comment: Если Вы не уверены в ответе, то лучше его не писать.

Comment: Уверен в том плане что дебаг там ЕСТЬ, в том числе и позволяющий дебажить под апачем. Но сам я им не пользовался, поэтому не могу рассказать в деталях как это работает. Просто поделился тем что знал. А так ребята знакомые вполне успешно юзали и хвалили.

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать мою разработку [Devel::DebugHooks](https://github.com/KES777/Devel-DebugHooks). Устанавливать:

```
cpanm Devel::DebugHooks
```

Для включения дебаггера апач нужно запускать с флагом `-X -DPERLDB`. Я запускаю апач через мейк файл, в котором у меня записано следующее:

```
debug: stop
        @${APACHE2_BIN} -X -DPERLDB -f ${CONF}/apache2.conf
```

и конфиг файл должен содержать следующее:

```
<IfDefine PERLDB>
        # PerlSetEnv PERL5OPT d:DebugHooks::Server=NonStop
        # Если используете модуля в домашней директории, то нужно прописать сюда ваш PERL5LIB
        # PerlSetEnv PERL5LIB /home/kes/perl_lib/lib/perl5
        # Данное решение не работает из коробки, тк. нужно ещё править баги в Apache::DB
        # Если исползовать стандартный дебаггер, то можно обойтись и без правок в Apache::DB
        PerlSetEnv PERL5DB "use Devel::DebugHooks::Terminal qw/NonStop trace_flow/; 1"

        <Perl>
                BEGIN {
                        use APR::Pool;
                        use Apache::DB ( );
                        Apache::DB->init;
                }
        </Perl>

        <Location />
                PerlFixupHandler Apache::DB
        </Location>
</IfDefine>
```

Обращаю внимание на то, что тут показаны опции необходимые для запуска дебаггера. Чтобы стартовать ваше приложение под апачем, нужно правильно отконфигурировать это ваше приложение.

Если есть вопросы по дебаггеру, добро пожаловать в [IRC канал](https://chat.mibbit.com/?channel=%23debughooks&server=irc.perl.org)